# Are there any iOS devices equipped with arm64 architected CPU?

Tags: cpu, device, arm64

Some old libraries just don't support arm64, but I found it's default in XCode5.1, are there any iOS devices using this instruction set? Currently, I just don't want it and removed it from the Build Settings, will there be any problem?

Comment: Yes the iPhone 5S, iPad Air and iPad mini 2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can't support arm64, it's safe to remove it. All arm64 devices also support 32-bit.

Comment: Thank you,Ian!So I'm safe and don't need to worry about it any more,that's great!!

Comment: The only real effect will be extra memory usage if all other currently running apps on the device are arm64, since multiple versions of the common frameworks will have to be mapped to memory. But this shouldn't be an issue for some time to come.

Answer (score 3):

All A7 devices are arm64. Currently that includes iPhone 5s, iPad Air, and iPad Mini Retina.